# D3 Zoom translateExtent not applied

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using D3 v4 to make a responsive barchart. I used this example by Mike Bostock: [Brush & Zoom](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172)

I want to implement the translateExtent to only translate in x direction but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. The g Element jumps to a specific position when I try to drag it.

My code for the setup:

```
margin = {top: margins.top, right: margins.right, bottom: margins.bottom, left: margins.left};
    width = size.width - margins.left - margins.right;
    height = size.height - margins.top - margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("#" + container).append("svg")
    .attr("class", "svgWrapper_" + container);

var cont = svg.append("g")
    .attr('class', 'mainContainer_' + container)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"); 

svg.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + .margin.bottom);

    svg.call(d3.zoom()
        .translateExtent([[0, 0],[width, height]])
        .on("zoom", function () {
            cont.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
        }))
        .on("dblclick.zoom", null)
        .on("wheel.zoom", null);
```

Comment: Can you provide the code in jsfiddle to check?

Comment: This is a simplified version. I think I simply don't understand how it works...[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fwzpmgpL/2/)

Answer (score -1):

I solved it testing... I didn't get it with the official explication: [d3js](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/master/README.md#zoom_translateExtent)

But to try it here is the adapted jsfiddle I used to test out the translateExtent: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fwzpmgpL/3/)

```
var zoom = d3.zoom()
.translateExtent([[-300, 0], [600 , height ]])
.on("zoom", zoomed);

svg.call(zoom);

function zoomed() {
  circle.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}
```

I still don't know why the translateExtent in the first jsfiddle didn't work, but I already implemented it in my chart and it works.